# django choicefield populated by values in external database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How can I populate a django `choicefield` with values from an external database? The DB is SQL Server. I have the database defenition set up in my app settings. I also have a model defined. I'm just not sure how to access or traverse the data at all.

`settings.py`

```
'an_external_db': {
    'NAME': 'DBName',
    'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
    'USER': 'MyUser',
    'PASSWORD': 'MyPassword',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'FreeTDS',
        'dsn': 'MYdsn',
    }
},
```

`models.py`

```
class ReadOnlyTest(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_DATABASE = 'an_external_db'
    field1 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column='Column1')
    field2 = models.CharField(db_column='Column2')
    field3 = models.CharField(db_column='Column3')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.field1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'TableName'
        managed = False
```

How can I populate a select drop down with values from like `field1` for example?